# How to identify AWS component by IP address lookup?

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc

I have apps deployed in AWS, like elastic search and ec2 instances inside VPC. Is there any service I can use to lookup the type of service running on the IP address from my VPC log. All my components are inside VPC I have the vpc log to get the ip address , Mostly it's all private ipv4 addresses.

Any API in python or Java will be helpful.

Comment: Short answer, no there is no such type of service/functionality. If you need to trace the internal IP back to the originating resource you should organize your resources into specific subnets (IE: Subnet 1 & 2 for EC2, subnet 3 & 4 elastic search). Or you could query each API for all your resources and match them by IP

Answer (score 1):

There is no service to identify the service. However you can get an idea on what that IP is associated with via `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces`